# Set an URL in laravel from environment variable

Tags: laravel

I have a form in my HTML, in the action, I would like to set the page where I want to send the data:

```
 <form action="wherever.com" method="post" target="_blank" style="display: inline;">
```

The problem is Laravel, in my .env file I set this:

```
WHEREVER_FORM="http://wherever.com"
```

Ok, now I want to set this env variable in my ACTION, I have tried with this:

```
action="env('WHEREVER_FORM')"
```

Also this:

```
action="env(WHEREVER_FORM)"
```

And this:

```
action="{{env('WHEREVER_FORM')}}"
```

I know that I can do this from a env variable, but I don´t find how to do it, in the Laravel Documentation I found this:

```
$env = env('APP_ENV');

// Return a default value if the variable doesn't exist...
$env = env('APP_ENV', 'production');
```

This is not enough to me.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  your .env file setup is ok:

```
WHEREVER_FORM="http://wherever.com"
```

And also:

```
<form action="{{env('WHEREVER_FORM')}}" method="post" target="_blank" style="display: inline;">
```

**However, Please make sure that you reboot your application after changing .env file. You can do this by:**

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Thanks, I have lost a lot time with this =(